# Can a method return a file?

Tags: java, file, types, return

I have a problem with my Java code. 
I want to pass a file (xml file for accuracy) as argument of input to a method. I paste my code:

```
public File searchPlaces(){

     URL url = getClass().getResource("arml.xml");
     File file = new File(url.getPath());

     return file;
}
```

I have a NullPointerException when I try to call this method.

Somebody could help me?

Comment: Which line throws the null reference exception?

Comment: Your XML file is not found (`url` is null I guess)

Comment: log trace? which line you are getting prob?

Comment: I've debugged, and the url is null. I must include the path of the file?

Answer (score 2):

You fail to check that the "url" is initialized with a non-null value.

Once you have a valid non-null URL, you can attempt to create a `File` object from it.  You might have to check that the file is also non-Null (or perhaps this method is allowed to return null items).  Either way, returning a null item (File or otherwise) is perfectly acceptable within Java.

De-referencing a null (calling a method on an object reference that doesn't refer to anything) is not.  That's why you get the error, at

```
url.getPath()
```

You're just misidentifying where it is failing.

Comment: I've debugged, and the url is null. I must include the path of the file?

Comment: It depends.  You are attempting to load the file relative to a Class.  If the file is packaged inside of a `JAR` file, this is the right way to do things.  If the file is located somewhere independent of the Class's location, then you should probably ski the `Class.getResource(...)` and open the `File` directly with one of the `File` methods.  Assuming you do want to load from a Class, then I would try again with an absolute path (from the root of the  jar file), like `/com/myname/mydir/arm1.xml`

Comment: It return NullPointerException, I modify my code: URL url = getClass().getResource("C:\\WebS\\test\\arml.xml");

Comment: @user917651, you are trying to grab a file at a location that is not related to the location of your Class.  Use `new File` instead of `getClass().getResource(...)` because the file is not at a location relative to the class.

Comment: Could you post an example please?

Comment: @user917651, `File myfile = new File("C:\\WebS\\test\\arm1.xml");`  Please learn how to read the javadoc at `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/io/File.html`, and please learn how to accept answers and set your user name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You might get a null pointer, if the new File() call generates an exception.

Debug and see if you the Url is not-null.

Comment: I've debugged, and the url is null. I must include the path of the file?

Comment: Yes. URLs should have a scheme to start with. Refer to this. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: It return NullPointerException, I modify my code: URL url = getClass().getResource("C:\\WebS\\test\\arml.xml");

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do. Try this and debug. getClass().getResource("\arml.xml");

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do here is not return a File object, but rather a BufferedReader or  FileReader, or maybe a FileInputStream.  Then, encapsulate all of your error handling within the method using a try/catch or bubble the errors up with a throws declaration.